# Software rendering - compose View matrix

Tags: c++, mathematics

There is function compose View Matrix, it's software rendering project. Used fixed point math. phd_sin() and phd_cos() user defined functions implement sin() and cos(). Please explain this calculations, where is there vector Right, Up, Look, like in View matrix from DX for example? How composed View matrix in this case (below)? I dont know this approach.

````
typedef struct PHD_3DPOS {
    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
    int32_t z;
    int16_t x_rot;
    int16_t y_rot;
    int16_t z_rot;
} PHD_3DPOS;

#define W2V_SHIFT 14

#define TRIGMULT2(A, B) (((A) * (B)) >> W2V_SHIFT)
#define TRIGMULT3(A, B, C) (TRIGMULT2((TRIGMULT2(A, B)), C))

typedef struct PHD_MATRIX {
    int32_t _00;
    int32_t _01;
    int32_t _02;
    int32_t _03;
    int32_t _10;
    int32_t _11;
    int32_t _12;
    int32_t _13;
    int32_t _20;
    int32_t _21;
    int32_t _22;
    int32_t _23;
} PHD_MATRIX;

#define MAX_MATRICES 40

PHD_MATRIX m_MatrixStack[MAX_MATRICES] = { 0 };

PHD_MATRIX g_W2VMatrix = { 0 };

void phd_GenerateW2V(PHD_3DPOS *viewpos)
{
    int32_t sx = phd_sin(viewpos->x_rot);
    int32_t cx = phd_cos(viewpos->x_rot);
    int32_t sy = phd_sin(viewpos->y_rot);
    int32_t cy = phd_cos(viewpos->y_rot);
    int32_t sz = phd_sin(viewpos->z_rot);
    int32_t cz = phd_cos(viewpos->z_rot);

    m_MatrixStack[0]._00 = TRIGMULT3(sx, sy, sz) + TRIGMULT2(cy, cz);
    m_MatrixStack[0]._01 = TRIGMULT2(cx, sz);
    m_MatrixStack[0]._02 = TRIGMULT3(sx, cy, sz) - TRIGMULT2(sy, cz);
    m_MatrixStack[0]._10 = TRIGMULT3(sx, sy, cz) - TRIGMULT2(cy, sz);
    m_MatrixStack[0]._11 = TRIGMULT2(cx, cz);
    m_MatrixStack[0]._12 = TRIGMULT3(sx, cy, cz) + TRIGMULT2(sy, sz);
    m_MatrixStack[0]._20 = TRIGMULT2(cx, sy);
    m_MatrixStack[0]._21 = -sx;
    m_MatrixStack[0]._22 = TRIGMULT2(cx, cy);
    m_MatrixStack[0]._03 = viewpos->x;
    m_MatrixStack[0]._13 = viewpos->y;
    m_MatrixStack[0]._23 = viewpos->z;
    g_W2VMatrix = m_MatrixStack[0];
}

```
````

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet which you posted defines 3D positions and matrices along with helper functions `phd_sin()` and `phd_cos()` for trigonometric operations using fixed-point arithmetic. The function `phd_GenerateW2V()` generates a World-to-View transformation matrix based on given Euler angles **(x_rot, y_rot, z_rot)** representing rotation around the X, Y, and Z axes respectively. The resulting W2V matrix stores the translation component (view position) and three orthogonal basis vectors: Right, Up, and Looking direction (which corresponds to Forward in typical coordinate systems). These basis vectors are computed using sine and cosine values derived from the input rotations. The generated matrix is stored in the global variable **g_W2VMatrix**.